# Multiple left join in ADO excel

Tags: sql

The below SQL query has a syntax error, how can I solve it?

```
SELECT [CREDITORS$].[Account Code], [CREDITORS$].[Name], Sum([CREDITORS$]![Base Amount]*-1) AS BillAmt," & _
      "SUM([SERVICETAX$].[Base Amount]) AS STAMT, Sum(([CREDITORS$]![Base Amount]*-1)-[SERVICETAX$]![Base Amount]) AS TDS " & _
      "FROM [CREDITORS$] LEFT JOIN [SERVICETAX$] ON [CREDITORS$].[Transaction Reference]=[SERVICETAX$].[Transaction Reference]" & _
      "LEFT JOIN [MASTER$] ON [MASTER$].[Account Code]=[CREDITORS$].[Account Code]" & _
      "GROUP BY [CREDITORS$].[Account Code], [CREDITORS$].[Name];
```

Comment: What does the syntax error say exactly?
And a proper formatting of the query can make it much more readable and understandable for others.

Comment: use `debug.print` to print out your query, Then see the answer you will.

Answer (score 1):

On a dynamic query you need add space in before of `LEFT JOIN` and `GROUP BY`, that was missed in the query. So adding the space in end of the line will work.

So the below query will work:

```
"SELECT [CREDITORS$].[Account Code], [CREDITORS$].[Name], Sum([CREDITORS$]![Base Amount]*-1) AS BillAmt, " & _
"SUM([SERVICETAX$].[Base Amount]) AS STAMT, Sum(([CREDITORS$]![Base Amount]*-1)-[SERVICETAX$]![Base Amount]) AS TDS " & _
"FROM [CREDITORS$] LEFT JOIN [SERVICETAX$] ON [CREDITORS$].[Transaction Reference]=[SERVICETAX$].[Transaction Reference] " & _
"LEFT JOIN [MASTER$] ON [MASTER$].[Account Code]=[CREDITORS$].[Account Code] " & _
"GROUP BY [CREDITORS$].[Account Code], [CREDITORS$].[Name];"
```

You actual query will return as the below, it won't have proper spacing.

```
SELECT [CREDITORS$].[Account Code], [CREDITORS$].[Name], Sum([CREDITORS$]![Base Amount]*-1) AS BillAmt, SUM([SERVICETAX$].[Base Amount]) AS STAMT, Sum(([CREDITORS$]![Base Amount]*-1)-[SERVICETAX$]![Base Amount]) AS TDS FROM [CREDITORS$] LEFT JOIN [SERVICETAX$] ON [CREDITORS$].[Transaction Reference]=[SERVICETAX$].[Transaction Reference]LEFT JOIN [MASTER$] ON [MASTER$].[Account Code]=[CREDITORS$].[Account Code]GROUP BY [CREDITORS$].[Account Code], [CREDITORS$].[Name];
```